# How to disable windows authentication for WEB API inside an ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with Windows authentication. Now I've added the web api to  it (nuget package) and want anonymous access (later on I'll add an api key). But I haven't managed to get it to work.

All my WEB API controllers are under the "/api" path, and none of them have the Authorize attribute.

Here's my current web.config (I removed all the bits and pieces that are irrelevant to this matter):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,:,&amp;,\" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="..." applicationName="..." />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <profile enabled="false" defaultProvider="AspNetProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="..." applicationName="..." />
      </providers>
      <properties></properties>
    </profile>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Generic">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/AccessDenied" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"></requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="Error">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

All my requests are getting "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized", but when I enter some valid windows credentials then the request executes successfully.

So, how can I disable the windows authentication for my WEB API? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in my MVC project properties and enabling anonymous authentication.

Comment: For the reference, could you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the authentication you can go to launchSettings.json, or just type "anonymous" into the find input field.

On top of the file you will then find "anonymousAuthentication", which you will have to set to true.

Later you can always switch to false again.